Unable to update @typescript-eslint dependencies to latest version
When updating npm packages manually I'm using the following command
npx npm-check -u

I'm getting errors and created a small package.json for reproduction
{
  "name": "reproduce",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
     "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "7.5.0",
     "@typescript-eslint/parser": "7.5.0",
     "eslint": "8.57.0"
  }
}

I want to update them to the latest version but it fails with
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: reproduce@0.0.0
npm error Found: eslint@9.6.0
npm error node_modules/eslint
npm error   dev eslint@"9.6.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@7.16.0
npm error node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm error   dev @typescript-eslint/parser@"7.16.0" from the root project
npm error   peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^7.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.16.0
npm error   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm error     dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"7.16.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error /home/me/.npm/_logs/2024-07-11T09_07_27_198Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/me/.npm/_logs/2024-07-11T09_07_27_198Z-debug-0.log
For more detail, add `--debug` to the command

I don't want to force the install because of

to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Should I wait until the maintainers fix it / the versions are compatible or are there any other solutions?

Based on this https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/8211 it seems I have to use an alpha version of @typescript-eslint
